# Add Telemetry logs in application insights of httptrigger function in .net core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

I have created http trigger function in .net core 3.1 but i am not able to add telemetry for logging in application insights.
I am using startup class and adding package Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions in csproj.

But I am getting this error

> An unhandled host error has occurred. [2021-06-17T13:08:55.752Z] Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'Google.Apis.ShoppingContent.v2_1.ShoppingContentService' while attempting to activate 'ShoppingSamples.Content.GoogleAuth'.

Is there any way i can add logs in application insights in http trigger function?

Comment: This has nothing to do with telemetry. It complains there's no `ShoppingContentService` registered with the DI middleware. Did you register the type in `Startup.ConfigureServices` ? What does your code look like?

Comment: can u guide me how to do that in startup class or share some link..cant i do without startup class..I only need to add log in application insights

Comment: Again, the error *has nothing to do with App Insights*. It complains you forgot to add *your own custom class* with `services.AddTransient`, `AddScoped` or `AddSingleton`. People can't help you if you don't post the code in `ConfigureServices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to make your logs from azure function(.net) be captured by azure application insights, you have to solutions:

one is [adding app insights instance to azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#enable-application-insights-integration) when you creating or created function instance in azure portal(that means codeless), see screenshot below, no other configurations.

[image]

Another is [adding sdk to the function project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-data), with the sdk you can also send custom telemetry(code-based). Don't forget to add `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` in `local.settings.json` file when debug in local environment.

[image]